# Document Managment System

Tags: google, document-management

We're looking for a way to use One Drive or Google Docs in a document management system that allows users to log into Civi, open up the documents folder and edit the document from within Civi, without ever leaving Civi.

Does something like this exist perhaps?

Many thanks

Comment: We are currently working on an integration of CiviCRM with Onlyoffice. It is however a rather large endevor and in an early stage. In case you are interested, let me know and I can keep you updated and/or sum up the work in an answer here.

Comment: Thank you @Fabian - will have a look into your offering

Comment: any update Fabian? or Grow?