# Does CiviCRM work with Sharepoint/Googledocs?

Tags: documentation, attachments, hyperlinks, document-management

I found this question from last year titled document management system.  I would like to investigate ways to link CiviCRM to something like Sharepoint/Googledocs.  Is there an update to this/some sort of extension?

Former question posted on StackExchange:
[Document Managment System](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37744/document-managment-system)

We're looking for a way to use One Drive or Google Docs in a document management system that allows users to log into Civi, open up the documents folder and edit the document from within Civi, without ever leaving Civi.

Does something like this exist perhaps?

Many thanks

Comment: can you pls add a link to the old question

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37744/document-managment-system

Answer (score 1):

See if the [Sharepoint extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sharepoint) does what you want.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  Some contacts on our system have a lot of documentation linked to them, ie. grant supporting documentation, monitoring/feedback info so it would be great to be able to click on a link within Civi to access this.   We're not using Case management though - does this matter?  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used this extension but it looks like it should be fine without Cases.